# When using Storybook.js with Lit components is there a way to have the "Show Code" display the markup for the component with the properties?

Tags: javascript, storybook, lit

I am using Storybook 7.0 and Lit 2.0.  When I click "Show Code" in a story, it only displays the tag for the component and not any of the properties that were set.  Is there a way to get the "Show Code" option to display the tags and all the properties that were set when using Lit?

```js
import { html } from "lit";
import type { Meta, StoryObj } from "@storybook/web-components";
import { DateFormatterProps } from ".";
import ".";

const Template = (args: DateFormatterProps) => {
  return html`
    <date-formatter 
      .date=${args.date} 
      .showHoursAndMinutes=${args.showHoursAndMinutes}
      .showDateOnly=${args.showDateOnly}
      .digitOnlyFormat=${args.digitOnlyFormat}
      .showSeconds=${args.showSeconds}
      ></date-formatter>
  `;
}

const meta: Meta<DateFormatterProps> = {
  title: "Date Formatter",
  tags: ['autodocs'],
  render: Template,
  parameters: {
    docs: {
      description: {
        component: "",
      },
    },
  },
  argTypes: {
    date: { control: "date",  description: "Date to format, can be a date object or a string that is valid for the Date constructor" },
  }
};
export default meta;

type Story = StoryObj;
export const Default: Story = {
  args: {
    date: new Date(),
    showHoursAndMinutes: true,
    showDateOnly: false,
    digitOnlyFormat: false,
    showSeconds: false,
  }
};
```

Comment: Hi is there any solution for this question? I'm facing same issue.

Answer (score 1):

You can bind the properties to the node's attribute values instead of the JavaScript properties.

So you could write your template like this:

```
const Template = (args: DateFormatterProps) => {
  return html`
    <date-formatter
      date=${args.date}
      show-hours-and-minutes=${args.showHoursAndMinutes}
      show-date-only=${args.showDateOnly}
      digit-only-format=${args.digitOnlyFormat}
      show-seconds=${args.showSeconds}
    ></date-formatter>
  `;
};
```

Note though that this only works for values that can be expressed as a string (e.g string, number, boolean).

Answer (score 1):

I am also looking for an answer. While I didn't find a perfect solution, this worked somewhat for my setup by setting `preview.parameters.docs.source.transform` in `preview.js`:

### Update:

This is a more reliable solution that walks through the raw input line by line and assigns the correct args to the correct elements.

It needs to set up a regex to find the custom element tags (in this case I used `/(?<=<eox-).*?((?=>| )|$)/gim`).

```
transform: (code, storyContext) => {
  /**
   * Check which props belong to which tag
   * and create object
   */
  const undecorated = storyContext.undecoratedStoryFn(storyContext);
  let currentTag = undefined;
  const tags = {};
  undecorated.strings
    .map((string, index) => {
      const startOfTag = string.match(/(?<=<eox-).*?((?=>| )|$)/gim);
      if (startOfTag) {
        currentTag = `eox-${startOfTag}`;
      }
      const property = string
        .match(/(?<=\.).*?(?==)/gim)?.[0]
        ?.replaceAll(" ", "");
      const value = undecorated.values[index];
      if (property && value) {
        if (!tags[currentTag]) {
          tags[currentTag] = {};
        }
        tags[currentTag][property] = value;
      }
    })
    .filter((l) => l);

  /**
   * Inject prop for each tag in the rendered code
   */
  Object.keys(tags).forEach((tag) => {
    code = code.replace(
      `<${tag}`,
      `<${tag}\n  ${Object.keys(tags[tag])
        .map(
          (key, index) =>
            `.${key}='\$\{${
              typeof tags[tag][key] === "string"
                ? tags[tag][key]
                : JSON.stringify(tags[tag][key])
            }\}'`
        )
        .join("\n  ")}\n  `
    );
  });
  return code;
},
```

### Previous solution:

```
transform: (code, storyContext) => {
  return code.replace(
    `<${storyContext.component}`,
    `<${storyContext.component} ${Object.entries(storyContext.args)
      .filter(([key]) => key !== "onLoadend")
      .map(
        ([key, value], index, row) =>
          `\n .${key}='\${${JSON.stringify(value)}}'${
            index + 1 === row.length ? "\n" : ""
          }`
      )
      .join("")}`
  );
},
```

This gets the rendered code and injects a stringified version of all the `args` after the opening tag, using the formatting `.prop='${value}'`. I tried omitting the quotes (like `.prop=${value}`), but that seems to mess up the syntax highlighting.